# Clipping shapefile using another shapefile in python using geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, gis, geopandas

I am using the code

import os
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr
import geopandas as gpd

def soilfunction(x, y, modelsize, output_path, input_path, model_limit_poly):
os.system("ogr2ogr -spat {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(x-modelsize/2, y-modelsize/2, x+modelsize/2, y+modelsize/2, output_path, input_path))
shp = gpd.read_file(output_path)# the file which has to be clipped
shp2 = gpd.read_file(model_limit_poly)# the file used as mask
shp2 = gpd.clip(shp, shp2)
shp2.to_file(output_path)
return()

and I am getting this warning.

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geopandas/tools/clip.py:67: DeprecationWarning: In a future version, `df.iloc[:, i] = newvals` will attempt to set the values inplace instead of always setting a new array. To retain the old behavior, use either `df[df.columns[i]] = newvals` or, if columns are non-unique, `df.isetitem(i, newvals)`
clipped.loc[

I have used bounding box method etc. where same warnings appear. Any recommendations to remove this warning??